# wchar implementation of a simple Caesar cipher in C

Tags: c, localization, wchar

I am writing a simple Caesar implementation for Amharic- one of the languages widely spoken in Ethiopia. Here is the code

```
main(){
         setlocale(LC_ALL, " ");
         int i, key=0;
         wchar_t message[20];
         wprintf(L"Enter message:>");
         fgetws(message, sizeof(message), stdin);
         wprintf(L"Enter cipher key:>");
         wscanf(L"%d", &key);
         /* basic input validation goes here */
         for(i=0;message[i]!='\0'; i++){
                 message[i]=message[i]+key;
          }
       wprintf(L"The cipher is: %ls", message);
       wprintf(L"\n");
  return 0;
   }
```

The code compiles without a warning. Works fine if key is less or equal to 5. The problem comes when key value is 6 and above. It prints one additional char so far as I tested it. I ran it through gdb to see where it's picking up the additional char. But couldn't make much sense. Here are my question:

1. Why does it work for the key 0 to 5 but not above?
2. Where does it get the additional char it prints for key grater than 5?

If it helps the sizeof wchar on my machine is 4byte.

Thank you

EDIT:

sample input:

```
                message: ተደለ
                key: 6 
                output: ቶዶሎ 0010
                output I expect ቶዶሎ
```

The 0010 is displayed like those chars without a corresponding symbol on the unicode table.

Thanks again.

Comment: Edit the question and add message, key and resulting output. Add also the output you expected to get.

Comment: Your code doesn't wrap the alphabet. In the latin alphabet, if you have an offset of three and encode a `z`, you should get a `c`. With your code, you'll get a closing curly brace `}`, which is three positions after the `z` in the Unicode table. So look for strange characters in the Unicode range after the Amharic alphabet. (You also unconditionally convert all characters, regardless whether they are space or punctuation, which doesn't make for nicely formatted messages.)

Comment: @Oehm, thanks but that will be handled by the input validation; and eventually going to rap the encryption on a separate function but what I didn't understand now is why it displays one extra char when key is above 5 and works fin for key less than 5.

Comment: The extra char you see is the wide-char newline (`0x0a`) that is kept in the string read with `fgetws` and that you wrap by 6 chars, resulting in `0x10`. That doesn't seem to be a printable character - that's why the terminal decides to print the character code as plain hex numbers. Remove the trailing new-line before wrapping or wrap conditionally.

Comment: @Oehm, many thanks that answers my question. I didn't know it also shift replace the newline char at the end of the input. How could I vote/accept you answer?

Comment: @TadeleT: Good to hear that your question is answered. I've rewritten my comment as answer, so you can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra char you see is the wide-char newline (`0x000a`) that is kept at the end of the string you read with `fgetws` and that you shift by 6 chars, resulting in `0x0010`. That doesn't seem to be a printable character and the terminal decides to print the character code as plain hex numbers.

Remove the trailing new-line before shifting or shift only printable characters.